# How to copy a file from device to app folder with Intel XDK?

Tags: android, cordova, intel-xdk

I need in my app a function (input type="file") so the user can copy a image from his device into a folder (/imgProducts) in my app in the same device. I tried with PHP, AJAX and XMLHTTP methods and all works fine when I try it as a website BUT when I try in Intel XDK the image is never copied.

Just in case, I added the "Folder" plugin in the project and tried in emulator AND device but still is not working.

Can anybody give me a Intel XDK compatible sample for this(Because I can´t find it in the official documentation) which I can apply?

Its necessary to give permissions to the folder imgProducts? and if so how can I give that permissions?

Thank you all.

Comment: Try searching for a Cordova or PhoneGap solution. The XDK creates standard Cordova apps, so programming solutions for Cordova or PhoneGap will also apply to the XDK.

Answer (score -1):

I gave up of trying and I solved it converting the images into Blob and saving into a IndexedDB database and now works like a charm. I recommend this method.